# Cannot convert OpenCV Mat to dlib arrray2D

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, dlib

I am using the following code to convert an cv::Mat into dlib array2D (which is required to track objects through dlib correlation tracker)

```
int main()
{

cv::Mat img = cv::imread("wine_plant.jpg");
dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> dlib_img(img);



return 0;
}
```

But while debugging I get the following error message.

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const cv::Mat' to 'IplImage'   yolo_cywine c:\users\antho\documents\c++\dlib-19.7\source\dlib\opencv\cv_image.h    37
```

Based on other issues already opened on the same matter, I also tried this

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("wine_plant.jpg");
dlib::cv_image<unsigned char> dlib_img(img);
```

But same result.

Am I missing something or is there something I am doing wrong? Could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: array2d<rgb_pixel> dlib_img;
        dlib::assign_image(dlib_img, dlib::cv_image<bgr_pixel>(img));

Comment: I tried that but still the same errror message 'error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const cv::Mat' to 'IplImage'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dlib version `19.7` seems too old. I also faced similar error on dlib `19.19` downloading from its website. It was fixed on github, but http://dlib.net/ did not contain the fixes when I used it. For me compiling from source solved it. Newer dlib version should fix this error.

These issues discuss this problem,

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1955

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1949

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2071

Changes to `cv_image.h`,

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/commits/master/dlib/opencv/cv_image.h

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/commit/54a9a5bbf3267386dd39a82fb792bab1bb60796c#diff-7c8f1a39b770981bf2d3a132da6f083b130b7c52cd994dbccb1d2115f0d729fd

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/commit/a4bf6e1e6afef5c55414164dc4414908d91a8be5#diff-7c8f1a39b770981bf2d3a132da6f083b130b7c52cd994dbccb1d2115f0d729fd